# post-receive hook not responding to the push from my local machine

Tags: git, shell, deployment, githooks, continuous-deployment

I have the following script as a `post-receive` git hook on the server. It is meant to automate the deployment whenever a git push is made.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH=dev
WORKING_DIR=/300gb/project
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    # there can be multiple branches but we're only interested in deploy
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH" == "$branch" ]; then
      echo "**** pulling changes from $branch ****"

      # change directory to the working copy
      cd $WORKING_DIR
      unset GIT_DIR
      git fetch
      git reset --hard origin/$DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH

      # at this point you have the latest source in WORKING_DIR.
      # time to start your build process and deployment scripts
      # grunt, for instance
      yarn install
      yarn run doc
      forever restartall
    fi
done
```

But when I made the push from my local machine to the `dev` branch, nothing happened. The script was never invoked. What could be the reason for this? I have changed the permission of the hook to `777`.

Comment: Are you using any hosting service? Like gitlab or github.

Comment: @ElpieKay github

Comment: Github does not support git hooks. It uses its own webhooks, https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: @ElpieKay Are you sure?? Other hooks work fine.

Comment: Do you mean "github" by "the server"?

Comment: @ElpieKay github as a service